# Running a Flask App on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Different Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a Flask application on EBS, but the structure of my app is different to that of the recommended setup and I haven't figured out how to run it.

Right now this is what it looks like:

- Project_Folder/

  - Project_App/

    - static/
    - templates/
    - `__init__.py` (I have application = app = flask.Flask(**name**) here)
    - `config.py`
    - views/

      - `__init__.py`
      - `index.py` (where my routes are defined)
  - `setup.py` (python package configuration)

To run the app, I go into the Project_Folder and export `FLASK_APP=Project_App`, and other environmental variables, and then do: `flask run`.

I know that EBS needs a `.py` file with "application" inside it so I am also able to run the app by doing python `__init__.py` from inside the Project_App. I made sure to change the WSGIPath to my `__init__.py` in hopes that it would find the application object in there, but it is still unable to run.

The logs aren't very helpful, but does anyone have any ideas? I am not really sure what goes on on the Amazon side to run the app itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up finding any other solution to this? Currently facing this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be having the same problem. If you use your eb-cli and type the command "eb logs" you should get a error log. If go through them and find an error that says something like "The target WSGI script '...' does not contain WSGI application 'application'", and you're currently getting a 403 Forbidden error, then your problem probably similar to mine. I'm assuming that in your **init**.py file you're using a application factory like:

```
def create_app():
    application = Flask(__name__)
    app = application
```

If you are, it's the application factory create_app() that's causing your issue. I'd advise try not defining application within create_app() or just not using the application factory at all